# Firebase looping through to subscribe to multiple childReferences

Tags: javascript, firebase

Ok so I have a bunch of childrefs in an array so:

```
var fireRef = "https://mybase.firebaseio.com/"
var baseRef = ["child1", "child2", "child3"];
for (var z = 0; i < baseRef.length; z++) {

   fireRef.child(baseRef[z]).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var msgData = snapshot.val();
        console.log(msgData);
        alert(msgData);
   });
}
```

this is on the client side so obviously it's blocking and ends up making the page unresponsive. So basically I want to subscribe to a bunch of child refs in an array. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: These examples are calling .child() on a string; presumably that's just a typo. However, I don't really understand what you mean by blocking. Each iteration calls the asynchronous child_added method, so  if you simply remove the alert(), they should not block.

Comment: Ok gave this an update. Got it working now so instead of calling a new firebase for each child I have a main firebase reference and add children with fireRef.child(baseRef[z]). So it loops and adds a watch for all children added.